# Citation problem with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, achemso

I have some problems with citations with natbib. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1 % if your are submitting a pdflatex (i.e. if you have
             % images in pdf, png or jpg format)

\usepackage{jcappub} % for details on the use of the package, please
                     % see the JCAP-author-manual

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % if needed

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}  

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\bibliography{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\citep{Mondal2020}
\end{document}
```

And here's my `.bib` file:

```
@ARTICLE{Mondal2020,
       author = {{Mondal}, Sushovan and {Ali}, Saif and {S}, Shanima and {Banerjee}, Narayan and {Mortuza Hossain}, Golam},
        title = "{Propagation of gravitational waves in various cosmological backgrounds}",
      journal = {arXiv e-prints},
     keywords = {General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology},
         year = 2020,
        month = apr,
          eid = {arXiv:2004.13554},
        pages = {arXiv:2004.13554},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {2004.13554},
 primaryClass = {gr-qc},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020arXiv200413554M},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Why when I'm trying to create pdf, I'm instead of citation receiving [?]? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two things: don't specify `.bib` and you should but `\bibliography` where you want the bibliography it is what is providing the data for cite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your test document:

- Most importantly, place the `\bibliography` directive not in the preamble, but inside the `document` environment, where you want the formatted bibliography to be typeset. Usually, this is toward the end of the document.
- The `jcappub` package loads `natbib` automatically. If you want authoryear-style citation call-outs, you need to place the `authoryear` option among the document class options.
- The `@article` entry type is not right for the entry at hand. It really ought to be `@misc`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,authoryear]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{Mondal2020,
      title={Propagation of gravitational waves in various cosmological backgrounds}, 
      author={Sushovan Mondal and Saif Ali and Shanima S and Narayan Banerjee 
              and Golam Mortuza Hossain},
      year={2020},
      eprint={2004.13554},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      url={https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.13554},
      primaryClass={gr-qc}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{jcappub} % this package loads 'natbib' automatically
\bibliographystyle{achemso}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\citep{Mondal2020}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```